# Sort an imported table as a 2 column table in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I have imported a 2 axis column, and I'm trying to convert it in a 2 column table.

The original table has this structure:

```
Date jan feb mar apr ...
1    a   b   c   d
2    e   f   g   h
3    i   j   k   l
4    m   n   o   p
...
```

And I want to display the data as:

```
jan1  a
jan2  e
jan3  i
...
feb1  b
feb2  f
...
```

The specific database is:

```
=ImportXML("http://www.sii.cl/pagina/valores/uf/uf2015.htm";"//*[@id='contenido']/table//tr")
```

I've tried with QUERY(), but couldn't manage to do it.

Comment: Do you want a solution written in code, as opposed to a function?

Comment: I was trying to implement it using QUERY function. I managed to do a "SELECT Col1, Col2", but couldn't manage to append Col1, Col3; Col1, Col4, ... I would prefer using an in-cell function, but any solution will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
={ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(text(SPLIT( CONCATENATE(if(row(B2:E5),B1:E1) &"-"&A2:A5  & "|"),"|"),"mmm-d"))),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(B2:E5&"-")),"-"))}
```

[Example file with the formula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UyXf1Uogj8wYB5y30UmU2hlC3lEmmPUlWVz3Y2MQRjQ/edit?usp=sharing)